# generate a list of selectable tags for a jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, devops

I've got an input step that can do this just fine:

```
      stage('get tags') {
         steps {
               script {
                    tags = sh(script:"git ls-remote --t --refs git@gitserver:my_repo1.git", returnStdout: true).trim()
                    tags = (tags =~ /(?m).*refs\/tags\/(.*)/).collect{it[1]} 
                    selected_tag = input message: 'Select a tag:', 
                                      parameters: [choice(choices: tags, name: '')]                 
               } 
         }
      }
```

Im trying to do the same thing using the active choice parameters, but having no luck.  i've simplified it to below just to test if the code is actually getting past the first line of the script, but it doesnt seem to.  if remove the lines defining the command and command.execute, it works fine.  when they are there, an ERROR is returned.

```
   properties([
      parameters([
         [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            description: 'Select a tag',
            filterLength: 1,
            filterable: true,
            name: 'select_tag',
            referencedParameters: 'my_repositories',
            script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                  fallbackScript: [
                     classpath: [], 
                     sandbox: true, 
                     script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                  ],
                  script: [
                     classpath: [], 
                     sandbox: true, 
                     script: """
                        def command = ['git', 'ls-remote', '--t', '--refs', 'git@gitserver:my_repo1.git']
                        def proc = command.execute()
                        if (my_repositories == 'repo1') { 
                              return['aaa','bbb']
                        }
                        else {
                              return['ccc', 'ddd']
                        }
                     """.stripIndent()
                  ]
            ]
         ]
      ])
   ])
```

The error is:

> Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate
> {message=Select the tag to Use:,
> parameters=[@choice(choices=null,description=blah,name=)]} for
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.InputStep:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate
> {choices=null, description=blah, name=} for
> hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Anyone know the right way to do this using an Active Choice parameter?

Comment: Why not use the [Git Parameter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/)? It is designed exactly for this.

Comment: this isnt for GIT alone, it's also for aws ECR repos